# Invert a function containing integration term

Tags: integration, inverse, inverse-function

Consider this  simple equation 
$$ \tau(t)=\int\frac{dt}{a(t)},$$ where $\tau$ and $a$ are functions of $t$. Now, from this equation, how can I calculate $a(\tau)$ ?

Comment: You should not use the same symbol for the  limits of integration and the variable of integration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have deleted limits in my question. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Answer (score 3):

$\tau'(t)=\frac 1 {a(t)}$ so $a(t)=\frac 1 {\tau'(t)}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I need an equation of `a` as a function of $\tau$ i.e., the equation of $a(\tau$) not $a(t)$. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: $\tau$ is a function of $t$, not a number. If you want to find the function $a\circ \tau$ the answer is $a(\tau (t))=1/\tau'(\tau (t))$.